# Why Image is not showing if the name is used different language using PHP?

Tags: php

On my site, I have a registration page where a user can enter their data with different language like Bangla, English, German etc.

Now, I just save the data with Bangla language to the database table and the image name is like that:

[image]

Now On the profile page, the image is not showing?

[image]

but you can see that in console log it's showing exact name like the database table:

[image]

Even in FTP folder it's showing exact name:

[image]

I don't understand why it's not showing?

**Update:**

**Profile Page Header Section Code:**

```
<?php require_once('admin/init.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>ccrroipr</title>    
    <?php require_once('includes/css.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
```

**Databae Connection:**

```
try {
    $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/database'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'), array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));       

    $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

**Database table:**

[image]

Comment: webpage, database, file system may have different charsets?

Comment: @ildflue I'm using utf-8

Comment: Convert the file names to latin characters before saving.

Comment: I have added few code that I am using utf-8

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: can you not save the images with ascii characters? After all -if it's recorded in the db then the filename is not important - the db will serve up the name regardless

Comment: @RamRaider Good idea If I save the file name as a number and then can I add a string with that number when I will show that image?

Comment: But is it impossible to show the name like my original DB file name?

Comment: numbers might be harder to implement - afterall, how do you determine the next available number quickly and easily. Perhaps use a hash of something like the microtime? ie `$filename=sha1( microtime() );` save the file as that name and use that name in the db??

Comment: but why its not working with exact file name like on the db?

Comment: perhaps alter the collation of the column - take a look at https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: strange!! In my localhost. It's working but not on live server :(

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is the images location. You should get the uploaded image from browser. Navigate to your image, like 'http://site_domain/images/users/xxxxxx-0000.jpg'.
Most important that, you not use '?' character in your file name, because it is make bad URL and request. Or you should convert file name to URL friendly.